# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Кнопка перезагрузки значительно сместилась, и теперь к ней приходится тянуться, что не особо удобно.

Comment: @shampar Авторский текст и мой ответ содержали частицу *то*, зачем Вы ее удалили из вопроса?

Comment: У автора была частица? Тогда, наверное, должна была быть чёрточка .Правя вопрос, ответа Вашего не видел, простите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Перед нами сложносочиненное предложение. Предложения, входящие в состав сложносочинённого предложения (ССП), отделяются друг от друга запятыми.
([**1.2. Знаки препинания в сложносочинённых предложениях**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniyah.html))

(2) Частица ***то*** пишется через дефис. В данном предложении она употреблена для подчёркивания слова, к которому относится.

**Кнопка перезагрузки значительно сместилась, и теперь к ней приходится тянуться, что не особо-то удобно.**